# internet explorer outputs nothing when doing jQuery AJAX .get call - other browsers are fine

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

i hope you can help me with this one. The code is supposed to display mysql data using a php script returning XML (the backend script works fine delivering good XML - checked with my previous question on Stack Overflow).

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 to do a .get AJAX call - and i just can't get Internet Explorer to display even a bit. Chrome, Safari, Chromium, FireFox and Opera work just fine here - i wonder what i did wrong ?

I checked the problem about IE and jQuery and i found this piece of code that could help but it doesn't work :

```
function parseXml(xml)
{ 
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        xml = xmlDoc;
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Is there anything i can do to display my posts in Internet Explorer?

I put an "alert" at the beginning of the xml parsing function but Internet Explorer never gets there to display alert. Other browsers do. It seems it doesn't even execute the

```
function(xml) { bazinga_getposts(xml); }
```

from jQuery .GET

Thanks for any idea! The IE version is 8

Here is the full code:

```
var ajax_content_left=$("#ajax_content_left");
var ajax_content_left_pagination=$('#ajax_content_left_pagination');

function parseXml(xml)
{   
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        xml = xmlDoc;
    }

    return xml;
}           

$.get("bazinga_blob/getposts.php",
    { 
        category:"1", 
        post_tags:"", 
        language:"pl", 
        author:"1", 
        posts_per_page:"2", 
        current_page:"1", 
        order:"desc", 
        hard_limit:"", 
        show_hidden:"1"     
    }, function(xml) { bazinga_getposts(xml); },'xml'); 

function bazinga_getposts(xml) 
{   
    alert('found it');

    thexml=$(xml);
    thexml=parseXml(thexml);

    var fill_this='';
    var fill_pagination='';
    var ile_stron=thexml.find('LastPage').text();

    thexml.find('Post').each(function()
        {
            fill_this+='<h1>'+thexml.find('PostTitle').text()+'</h1>';
            fill_this+='<article>'+thexml.find('PostBody').text()+'</article>';

        });

    for (i=1;i<=ile_stron;i++)
    {
        fill_pagination+='<li><a href="#'+i+'">'+i+'</a></li>';     
    }

    ajax_content_left.append(fill_this);
    ajax_content_left_pagination.append(fill_pagination);
}
```

Comment: could you indent your code, please? (4 spaces before each line)

Comment: sure i'm getting to that in a sec, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the returned content is invalid XML; see if it works with plain text. Also, try setting an error callback. If all else fails, you can try to [debug it via Microsoft Script Editor](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: thanks Tgr, when i switch it to plain text - the function executes also in Internet Explorer but hooping through the each.find(' ')... doesn't return anything . The XML validates here: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp . In the php file i tried using these content-type headers: application/xml , application/xhtml+xml and text/html

Answer (score 2):

Discovered!

Thanks for help, i started digging the php script again and i found here: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery/2 a line that was missing: it was the:

**header("Cache-Control: no-cache");**

that was necessary to start displaying stuff in Internet Explorer

See you :)

Comment: Withour a nocache header, IE might use the browser cache instead of actually doing the query. Personally, I wouldn't trust it to behave correctly even with the header specified - it is safer to break caching by appending some random string to the query. jQuery takes care of that if you set [the cache parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to false.